# Where is my mistake(s) in my solution?

Tags: calculus

A curve is defined by the parametric equations $x=t^2$ and $y=\sin(t)$, for $-\pi\lt t \le\pi$. Find

(i) $\frac {dy}{dx}$,

(ii) the equation of the tangent at the point $P(p^2,\sin p)$, where $0\lt p \lt\pi$,

(iii) the equation of the normal to the curve that is parallel to the *y*-axis.

The answers given are:

(i) $\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {\cos t}{2t}$

(ii) $y=-\frac {x\cos p}{2p}+\frac {p\cos p}{2}-\sin p$

(iii) $x=\frac {pi^2}{4}$

I am able to solve (i) but am stuck at (ii). Here are my solutions:

(i)
$$x=t^2$$
$$\frac {dx}{dt}=2t$$
$$y=\sin t$$
$$\frac {dy}{dt}=\cos t$$
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {\cos t}{2t}$$

(ii)
At $P(p^2,\color{red}-\sin p)$, $\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {\cos \sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}}=\frac {\cos p}{2p}$, therefore tangent of equation is:

$$y-(-\sin p)=\frac {\cos p}{2p}(x-p^2)$$
$$y=\frac {x\cos p}{2p}-\frac {p^2\cos p}{2p}-\sin p$$
$$y=\frac {x\cos p}{2p}-\frac {p\cos p}{2}-\sin p$$

My answer for (ii) is very close to the answer except for the signs for the first and second term on the RHS. When I plot the graph out using Desmos.com, I realised my answer is indeed wrong. However, I couldn't see where I have done wrongly.

Any help / advice is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I think there is a typo in part (ii) of the question. Aren't you asked to find the tangent line at $(p^{2},-\sin p)$ instead of $(p^{2},\sin p)$?

Comment: I have shown your mistake in red.

Comment: Yes it should be $-\sin p$. Apologies for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

$(p^{2},- \sin p)$ correspomds to $t=-p$ so you have to evaluate the derivative at $-p$.

Comment: Thank you. But why is $t=-p$ for $(p^2,-\sin p)$?

Comment: @IM_LOST Because $y=\sin t$.

Comment: I am still a bit confused. While we have: $y=\sin t$ and hence $-\sin p=\sin t$ which yields $t=-p$, we also have $x=t^2$ which means $p^2=t^2$ that gives $t=\pm p$. So why can't $t=p$?

Comment: The answer given is for the  tangent line at $(p^{2},-\sin p)$ but your answer is for the  tangent line at $(p^{2},\sin p)$ . $t=p$ does not correspond to the point $(p^{2},-\sin p)$. @IM_LOST